# chrome inspect element two rows instead two colums

Tags: google-chrome

in that picture u can see two columns in Google Chrome Inspect "Element and Style", how to make two rows " Element up and Style on Bottom" in same mobile view?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. With Developer Tools open, press **F1** to enter **Settings**.
2. Change **Panel Layout** to "**Horizontal**" under **Appearance**.